# How to run code in the background of a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, timer, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, background-task

I am working on a flutter app. I have a bunch of times of the day and I want to show an alert notification whenever a time comes and also change the UI of the app if it's running.

So I looked for what options I have, I found the followings

- Plugins like **flutter-workmanager** and **background_fetch**
- Native code implementation with Channels

MY questions are:

1. Which option is the best for my use case?
2. Is it better implementing a time counter with delay by duration or using an alarm manager.
3. How can I pass the data (the current time that comes) between the background task and my app so that I can update the UI?

PS: Currently We are interested in a solution that works at least for Android.

Comment: What do you need background tasks for? If you only need to show the notification, you can schedule it for specific datetime while you app is working without using background task.

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin I need to schedule the task and show the notification even if the app is not working (such as push notification but locally). And if the app was working when the time comes I need to update the UI with the current time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need background tasks just to show notifications. Using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) should be enough for your task. You can schedule a notification with this plugin for specific datetime. Inside of the app, you can use [Timer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to trigger at specific datetime. I'll show you a simple example:

[image: demo]

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifPlugin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification(DateTime dateTime, String title) async {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    if (dateTime.isBefore(now)) {
      // dateTime is past
      return;
    }

    final difference = dateTime.difference(now);

    Timer(difference, () {
      showDialog(
        context: this.context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(title),
          );
        }
      );
    });

    await notifPlugin.schedule(title.hashCode, title, title, dateTime, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'test');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container()
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text('planned notification'), duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
              scheduleNotification(DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 2)), 'Hello');
            },
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But if you need to do some calculations or data fetch then background_fetch is what you need. The only problem with it Apple don't allow background tasks in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but what I need is an app independent task responsible for showing notifications even when the app is down. This task will fetch the times from the server (each day) then schedule the notifications for that day (using flutter_local_notifications as you suggested).

Comment: @C.Mahfoud Have you tried using background_fetch or flutter-workmanager? Try to use any of those - they are wrapping the same native api, so there's not much difference between them.